# VBA - Due Date with Hours and Minutes?

Tags: excel, vba, date, time

Let's say I want a msgbox to pop up when something is an hour away from happening, how would this be done?

I'm thinking something along the line:

```
MyLimit = Now

If .Value = MyLimit Then
msgbox "Do that thing cause it is due right now"
```

or

```
MyLimit = Date

If .Value = MyLimit Then
msgbox "Do that thing cause it is due right now"
```

and have the formula refer to cell with a Date Formatting of "m/d/yy h:mm AM/PM"

Something like that doesn't work and I wonder why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Application.OnTime Method

```
Sub setAlarm()
    Application.OnTime Range("deadline").Value - TimeValue("01:00:00"), "my_Procedure"
End Sub

Sub my_Procedure()
    MsgBox "Do that thing cause it is due right now"
End Sub
```

The msgbox pops up one hour before the deadline

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll test it tomorrow once I'm back to work and let you know if it does it :) Looks good so far, I didn't know of this method.